# (Unity C#) Directory.CreateDirectory() not creating folder when it should

Tags: c#, file, directory, create-directory

Yes, exactly that. I try it with the proper syntax, and it doesn't create the folder. Here's my code:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("~/Library/Application Support/PROJECT_TITLE");
```

I should see a new folder appear in `~/Library/Application Support` called `PROJECT_TITLE`, right? I run it and trigger the function, and no errors pop up. Then I check in Finder, and the folder is not there!

**EDIT:**

Okay, so it turned out it was just putting all of those folders within the project folder itself. How can I make it so it does it from the root folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the "~" in the beginning since Library is inside the users directory. However, the real problem is that you can't just create another directory under Library because you'll just end up with "UnauthorizedAccessException". I'm not sure how but you'll have to do some DirectorySecurity modification for that. [DirectorySecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I already tried that, the problem is that it creates a new Library folder within Unity's project folder itself.